# getting unexpected HTML content with webview

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get the url content source code using [flutter webview plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin).. and i have written this code in order to get expected result but i don't know why this code is returning unexpected one line content..

My code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

const kAndroidUserAgent =
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Mobile Safari/537.36';


class mainController{
  Future getdata() async{
    var data;

    final flutterWebViewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();

    flutterWebViewPlugin.launch('https://www.instagram.com/picsart/?__a=1', hidden: true, userAgent: kAndroidUserAgent,);
     data =  await flutterWebViewPlugin.evalJavascript("window.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;");
    flutterWebViewPlugin.close();
    return data;
  }
}
```

Output that i get

```
I/flutter (21310): "\u003Chtml>\u003Chead>\u003C/head>\u003Cbody>\u003C/body>\u003C/html>"
```

what i was expecting is -
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to just grab Instagram JSON data? Why do you need to use FlutterWebView for that? You're not grabbing a webpage.

Comment: @ReyHaynes because some graph url of instagram can only be accessible when user is logged in and we can't do it with simple api call ...  and also instagram not allow to access user cookie

Answer (score 2):

I was trying a lot to get an answer. And I found a workaround. Below is the solution I found.

```dart
data =  await flutterWebViewPlugin.evalJavascript("encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML)");
data = Uri.decodeComponent(data);
```

What it does is, encode the component in JavaScript before bringing it. Then, decode the data in dart.

It worked when I am using webview_flutter pluggin. Probably it will work here also.

I know I am late, but adding answer for people who might have the same problem and end up here.

Comment: You are the best !!! Been struggling for hours...

Answer (score 0):

That is a JSON data feed, not a webpage. What that plugin is attempting to do is view the page as a webpage and that will disrupt the JSON data format.

Use `http` as described in the Flutter cookbook: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: because some graph api of instagram can only be accessible when user is logged in and we can't do it with simple api call ... and also instagram not allow to access user cookie

Comment: Well, for Instagram API access, you need to go through the process of getting credentials set up properly or you'd be breaking their TOS. You're only other hope is that they are already logged in via a desktop.

Comment: i just able to fetch the json data but i am still facing little issue ... can you help me to find out

Comment: I think you are missing the point. You can see the data on your computer because you are logged in within the same browser environment. Any attempt beyond that won’t work because you need your credentials to pass their Auth. If that is ok, then use the `http` method mentioned to get JSON data.

Comment: noop i am not missing any point i will ask user for login according to my app TOS and store the session and cookies in a app webview and then whenever user need to calculate some states related to there profile my app will do the background request on API url of instagram through existing session and cookie